# PostgreSQL Table Overlap Count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgresql.

I have a table that looks like this

```
|      id1       |       id2       |
------------------------------------
|       1        |        6        |
|       1        |        12       |
|       2        |        6        |
|       3        |        1        |
|       3        |        2        |
|       2        |        2        |
```

I am trying to design a query that given for example: id1=1, it will return all id1's with their overlap in id2 in relation to the given id1. Do not include the given id1 in the results.

For example, if it were given id1=1, the result should be:

```
|      id1       | num_occurences  |
------------------------------------
|       2        |        1        |
|       3        |        0        |
```

An id1 of 2 would return 1 because id1=1 and id1=2 have only id2=6 in common. id1 of 3 returns 0 because there is no overlap in occurrences.

I think I might want to use an INNER JOIN but I am not sure.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you also want zero results, you could use a LEFT JOIN to check the condition;

```
SELECT a.id1, COUNT(b.id1) num_occurences
FROM mytable a
LEFT JOIN mytable b ON a.id2 = b.id2 AND b.id1 = [id]
WHERE a.id1 <> [id]
GROUP BY a.id1
```

...where in your case, [id]=1.

What it does is check for each row in "b" (with id1=1) check if there's a row in "a" with the same id2 and an id1 <> 1. Then all it needs to do is group and count the results.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5c1b1/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id1, SUM(  CASE
    WHEN id1=id2 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END )
  AS num_occurences
FROM table
GROUP by id1
```

Not a single JOIN was given that day.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This appears to be summing the occurrences of id1=id2. This is not what the question is asking.

Comment: In that case, I misinterpreted what you meant with id1 overlapping with id2. Did you mean "what other rows have the same id2 as me, without counting me?"